# Remove empty lines in text using Visual Studio or VS Code

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code, line

How to remove empty lines in Visual Studio?

Comment: [For Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50042582/6597375)

Comment: Is there an answer for this without using regular expression? Just by using a shortcut like CTRL-K-D which formats the document but forgets to remove double blank lines.

Comment: How can we do this automatically in vs code when we format document or as we type? similar to what code maid does on visual studio?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

It's very useful especially if you want to arrange or compare codes, thanks to the people who answer this question, I've got the answer from [here](http://wblo.gs/VGx) and would like to share it with Stackoverflow:

**Visual Studio** (Visual Studio Code) has the ability to delete empty lines in replace operation using regular expressions.

- Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> (quick replace)
- Tick "Use Regular Expressions"
- In Find specify `^$\n`
- In Replace box delete everything.
- Click "Replace All"

All empty lines will be deleted.

Regular expression for empty line consists of

Beginning of line `^`

End of line `$`

Line break `\n`

Note that normally in Windows an end of line  indicated by 2 characters [crlf](/questions/tagged/crlf) - Carriage Return (CR, ASCII 13, `\r`) Line Feed (LF, ASCII 10, `\n`).

A regex to remove blank lines that are/aren't *really* blank (i.e. they do/don't have spaces):   `^:b*$\n`

To remove double lines:  `^:b*\n:b*\n` replace with: `\n`

*** for Visual Studio 2013 and above:***

```
^\s*$\n
```

and for double lines:

```
^(?([^\r\n])\s)*\r?\n(?([^\r\n])\s)*\r?\n
```

See the regular expression syntax updates for VS2012 and above in @lennart's answer below

Comment: Works like a charm with cleaning XML file in Visual Studio 2015. Anyone know how to make a shortcut to execute this?

Comment: Is there a way for this to work with the automatic formatter?

Comment: ^\s*$\n worked fine for me. :)

Answer (score 202):

Since Visual Studio 2012 changed its regex syntax, the original answers by Ala translate into the following in VS 2012:

**Remove single blank lines**

Old:

```
^:b*$\n
```

New:

```
^(?([^\r\n])\s)*\r?$\r?\n
```

Visual Studio 2013 (thanks to BozoJoe and Joe Johnston):

```
^\s*$\n
```

**Remove double blank lines**

Old:

```
^:b*\n:b*\n
```

New:

```
^(?([^\r\n])\s)*\r?\n(?([^\r\n])\s)*\r?\n
```

Rolls right off your tongue.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the conversion sheet from MSDN.

Comment: BozoJoe's answer, for me, worked well in VS2012 also (Update 4)

Comment: ^\s+$\n changed to ^\s*$\n allow for (no content) pure line feeds.

Comment: How can i make this automated, like working with CTRL+K+D?

Comment: Is this meant to work for strings or for code in the editor?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Primarily for code in the editor. I don't know if the syntax is the same for strings (if you mean the Regex.* classes)

Comment: Working with VS 2017

Comment: Working with VS 2019

Answer (score 33):

**Using Visual Studio 2017 and above**

in  **Current Document**

use shortcut

- Open  **Tools** > **Options** or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
- Under **Environment** tab > **Keyboard**
- Search for "**DeleteBlank**" and select `Edit.DeleteBlankLines`
- Add a new shortcut for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
- **Assign** >  **OK**

##### **select all text and hit the shortcut**

[image]

Comment: This only delete selected blank line(s) or from current line till the next non-blank line. It's not for the whole document or project.

Comment: Try a select all before running the command, then it'll work.

Comment: You should choose not used shortcut. I took Ctrl + Shift + Alt + D

Answer (score 20):

Tested in VS 2012 to allow for pure line feeds.

```
^\s*$\n
```

hth

Comment: this works for me in VS 2015, the accepted answer did not unfortunately

Comment: Works in VS 2013 as well.

Comment: Works well in VS 2017, the accepted answer does not.

Comment: Works in 2019 too

Comment: Works in VS2022 Note: a trailing space was treated as part of the pattern. be sure to trim

Answer (score 19):

In Visual Studio 2013 (Version 12.0.20623.01) i removed empty lines with this regular expression `^\r\n` In the screen you can see the matched lines indicated by the brown squares.

[image: Visual Studio 2013 replace empty lines]

Comment: I also tried such way, but visual studio stuck frozen for some minutes and then replaced only 1 occurrence of several hundred I have! lol :-D

Answer (score 10):

I'm using visual studio 2017, non of the above worked for me until I tried `\n\r`

Steps:

1. Ctrl + H (opens find and replace)
2. Select use regular expression (Alt + E)
3. Enter `\n\r` into the "Find..." input
4. Press replace

Answer (score 10):

**VS 2022 and 2019**

1. Open the replace box: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
2. Turn on regular expressions: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
3. Find: `^\s*$\n`
4. Replace: (leave empty)
5. Replace All:  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
6. Turn off regular expression: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
7. Hide the replace box: <kbd>Esc</kbd>
8. Format the document: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: also works in vs2022 :D

Comment: Find: `^\s$` is sufficient as this translates into, only whitespace characters between the beginning and the end of the line.

Comment: It works with Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise edition, I applied with 41.000 lines of code of DBContext. Nice answer!

Answer (score 9):

To remove two or more adjacent empty rows with VS2012 use this:

```
^(?([^\r\n])\s)*\r?$\r?\n^(?([^\r\n])\s)*\r?$\r?\n
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution to replace two empty lines into just one. It works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Install [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/) and hit <kbd>Ctrl+M, Space</kbd> to clean up the code. (It formats the code, like Format Document <kbd>Ctrl+E, D</kbd>, as well). You can clean up more files from Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 4):

To remove double lines:  ^:b*\n:b*\n replace with:  \n

Source: http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2008/03/04/remove-empty-lines-in--text-using-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: This answer is a repeating to the same answers above!

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2012, the regex string to use to find and replace all blank lines is ^(?([^\r\n])\s)\r?\n

Answer (score 0):

in VS2019 I just used ^..$ since none of the other answer actually worked.

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> auto formats the current document and that removes unnecessary space in your code. It helps keep your code readable if that what you were looking for.

Comment: i am referencing my issue , please look ,it looking ,this is something i was looking .

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747909/visual-studio-update-model-from-data-base-issue/44772280?noredirect=1#comment76526844_44772280.

Comment: This doesn't remove double/redeundant empty lines.