# Visual studio replace statement with empty row

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have situation like this for example

```
 ....
 statement1
 statement2
 <blank line>
 }
```

Now I want to delete `statement2` in the whole file(let's say it's on 20-30 places in the file). I can delete it with Find&Replace but this results in two blank lines before the closing bracket. In our project we're using StyleCop and thus he's not allowing to have multiple blank rows one after another. How can I delete all the statements and also remove the blank line after the deletion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're satisfied with a two-step solution, [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453160/remove-empty-lines-in-text-using-visual-studio/13987363#13987363) are a couple of RegEx expressions for removing blank lines.

In your case (matches two blank lines):

```
^(?([^\r\n])\s)*\r?\n(?([^\r\n])\s)*\r?\n
```