# What are the HTMLFILE.GIF and FOLDER.GIF?

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe

What are the HTMLFILE.GIF and FOLDER.GIF?

I have this classic ASP website which I am bringing into TFS. While looking at the Pending changes, I see those two files in many of the folders.

While doing some read it looks like they have something to do with VSS, since the project was in Visual Source Safe.

Here's a screen cap of search on web:

[image]

I think it would be safe to delete those two files(several of them) but wanted to check if that's going to affect anything?

Comment: They are not anything added or used by TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and deleted those files. There were like 160 files of each type.
I had similar Thumbs.db files as well which I manually selected in Pending Changes and Undo.

With these files I found that I can select multiple files in Undo dialog .

Sorted the files by Name

Selected First -> Shift + Select Last

Check one of the selected box and all the selected files got checked.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Realized that doing the above did not remove the reference from my .csproj files. i.e. It left this in the .csproj

```
<Content Include="somepath1\somedir2\dir3\Thumbs.db" />

<Content Include="somepath1\somedir2\dir3\HTMLFILE.GIF" /> 

<Content Include="somepath1\somedir2\dir3\FOLDER.GIF" />
```

So had to open that file and had to do search and replace:
Used this regex [Delete a line in file based on search criteria / Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130221/delete-a-line-in-file-based-on-search-criteria-regex/29130765#29130765):

```
<Content Include=".*?Thumbs.db.*?\/>
```

And then used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453160/remove-empty-lines-in-text-using-visual-studio) remove the empty lines:

```
^(?([^\r\n])\s)*\r?$\r?\n^(?([^\r\n])\s)*\r?$\r?\n
```

There might be easier ways, but some how I ended up doing this way (seems to be little hard)