# Delete a line in file based on search criteria / Regex

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-2013

I have a .csproj file which has entries like:

```
<Content Include="somepath1\somedir2\dir3\Thumbs.db" /> 

<Content Include="newpath\somedir2\Thumbs.db" /> 

<Content Include="anotherpath\somedir1\dir3\dir4\Thumbs.db" />
```

They are scattered all over the file.

What I am looking for is to use Visual Studio(Preferred) or other tool to delete the entire line by Search/Replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all the content include, you can use a simple regex like this:

```
<Content Include=.*?\/>
```

On the other hand, if you want to remove the thumbs then you can use

```
<Content Include=".*?Thumbs.db.*?\/>
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/nP7oM2/1)**