# Resharper: remove empty line before brackets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper

In Resharper 9.2 and Visual Studio 14 (2015), I would like to remove a blank line before a opening bracket on Cleanup Code(Ctrl+E, Ctrl+C). I cannot find a setting for this. Here is some sample code.

What I have:

```
namespace TestApp.Test

{
    public class Program

    {
        private string _foo;

        private string _bar;

        public string Qux { get; set; }

        private Program()

        {
        }
    }
}
```

What I want:

```
namespace TestApp.Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        private string _foo;

        private string _bar;

        public string Qux { get; set; }

        private Program()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The options 'Remove blank lines after "{" and before "}" in declaration' and 'Remove blank lines after "{" and before "}" in code' do not work for this issue.

When I set option 'Keep max blank lines in declarations' to '0' the blank line is removed, but also all the blank lines between fields and properties. Therefor, I would like to keep it at '1'.

What I don't want:

```
namespace TestApp.Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        private string _foo;
        private string _bar;
        public string Qux { get; set; }
        private Program()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to *Resharper->Options->Code Editing->C#->Formatting Style->Blank Lines*
2. Set 'Keep max blank lines in declarations' to '0'
3. Set 'Around single line field' to '1'
4. Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Using Visual Studio 2017

in  **Current Document** use shortcut

- Open  **Tools** > **Options** or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
- Under **Environment** tab > **Keyboard**
- Search for "**DeleteBlank**" and select `Edit.DeleteBlankLines`
- Add a new shortcut for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
- **Assign** > **OK**

select all text and hit the shortcut

[image]

in **Current Project** or **Entire Solution** use regular expressions

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12453161/10489223)

Visual Studio has an ability to delete empty lines in replace operation using regular expressions.

- Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> (quick replace)
- Tick "Use Regular Expressions" or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
- In Find specify `^\s*$\n|\r`
- In Replace box delete everything.
- Click "Replace All" or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue affects me as well, what I do to get around it is do a simple regex find and replace first, then do my ReSharper code cleanup.

Find

```
(\r?\n)(\r?\n)*(?([^\r\n])\s)*([{])
```

Replace

```
$2$3
```

This isn't really an answer, I would have put it in a comment but SO doesn't allow me to comment yet.  So I fully expect this to be flagged and deleted.  Hope you see it first, because I would really like your feedback when you find the real solution!

Comment: We do an auto cleanup on save and I can't ask my colleagues to do this, but maybe I can do this from time to time. I still hope a ReSharper option will be available/made for this. :-)